# Pre-made instances of a class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have class like this:

```
class result{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

`a,b,c` can be filled with any integer. However, there is some famous cases which I will use them too much like for example the zero case where **(a=b=c=0)** or the identity case where **(a=b=c=1)** and some others.

So I want an easy way to get this instances when I want one of them without creating new object and filling it manually (the real case contains much more complex that 3 integers).

What I am doing currently is like this:

```
class result{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    static result get_zero(){
         return result{0,0,0};
    }
    static result get_idenity(){
         return result{1,1,1};
    }
};
```

and in main:

```
auto id=result::get_identity();
```

Is this a good way to achieve what I want? Is there like an idiomatic way for doing this?

Comment: It is certainly not *the* right way to do this, there are other ways too. But it is one way to do it, nothing wrong with it so far.

Comment: probably not, you will get a fresh new instance every time the function is called

Answer (score 4):

If the objects can be modified after you return them, then yes, this is the correct way, since you cannot share a single object.

NRVO (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) and move-semantics remove any cost associated with returning the object by value.

If you know these objects will never be changed, you can return a `result const &` instead and have the object itself be a static member of your class.  At that point, you don't even technically need the getter/setter, since the static members are public and already marked as const.

```
class result{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    static result const zero_result{0,0,0};
    static result const & get_zero(){
         return result::zero_result;
    }
    static result const identity_result{1,1,1};
    static result const & get_idenity(){
         return result::identity_result;
    }
};
```

don't forget to allocate the memory for your static data members in a .cpp file, though:

```
result const result::zero_result;
result const result::identity_result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Conventionally we would probably just create a `static` instance that you can re-use, copy from etc.

```
// someFile.h
extern const result ZERO, ID;

// someFile.cpp
const result ZERO{0, 0, 0};
const result ID{1,1,1};
```

Alternatively, have your class own these instances as `static` members and have your functions return a reference.

To be honest, though, your current approach seems perfectly performant and may be the most easy-to-use.

Comment: You can even make those `constexpr`.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposal solution it's strongly compiler optimization efficiency. Actually when `result::get_identity();` is called a new `result` object is created and returned.

This will invoke the initialization constructor and, in the best case, the move constructor then.

Probably your compiler will optimize that with [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

---

One good approach it may be to create *const static* objects from your code can refer to.

For example in your class:

```
class Result {
  // something
  public:
    static const Result Zero;
    static const Result Identity;
};

// ... and then you can refer to it
do_something(Result::Zero);
```

In that way you can refer to object which will be created only once, when your program starts and avoid instantiating always a new notorious object.

Answer (score -2):

you could make a static class of your result and use that. i did this for a product i made in c# and it worked perfectly

Comment: maybe you mean object, not class?

Comment: Don't see what C# has got to do with anything